Unity - resolve IDistributedCache
I am trying to implement a Redis Distributed cache into a Net Framework 4.8 application. I am in the unfortunate position of having to downgrade a solution that was working perfectly fine  in Net Core 6, and I am no Unity expert.
I am registering the cache like this:
Application_Start() -> UnityConfig.RegisterComponents()
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("connectionString");
container.RegisterInstance(redis);

container.RegisterType<IDistributedCache<FeatureCollection>, GeoDistributedCache>();

When I hit an endpoint that makes use of the injected cache, it will respond with the following error message:
"No public constructor is available for type Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache"
Which I can then trace back to my injected class:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;

namespace Namespace.Caching
{   
    public class GeoDistributedCache : DistributedCache<FeatureCollection>
    {
        public GeoDistributedCache(IDistributedCache cache)
        {
            // other code here...
        }
    }
}

Where am I going wrong here? How should I wire up the Unity container for this to work?

I think you should do the following:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;

namespace Namespace.Caching
{   
    public class GeoDistributedCache
    {
        private IDistributedCache _cache;

        public GeoDistributedCache(IDistributedCache cache)
        {
            _cache = cache;
        }
}

And then install your redis cache package:
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis
dotnet add package StackExchange.Redis

Register your RedisCache:
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
    options.Configuration = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
    options.InstanceName = "RedisName";
});


No, this is the Net Core way of registering the distributed Redis cache. I need a solution for Net Framework.
